# Android) How to take multiple photos from Android Gallery and displayed in the 'WebView'?

Tags: android, webview, gallery

hello I am a novice developers.
I want multiple Photo from Android Gallery and display in the WebView.
Is it possible?
What function should I use? from android and web.
please tell me example source or references site.
thank you.

Comment: Why was a minus point in my question?
please tell me I'll modify. :'-0

Comment: I didn't downvote but the question as written is pretty broad. Can you post what you've tried so far and what's going wrong with it?

Comment: Ah.. I can't speak Engilsh well. :'-( so, difficult to describe in detail.
I want.. 
Android Phone Gallery 6 Picture-input-> WebView (post 6picture)
Is it possible if "use Multipart?